# R-EXT connection on the STP16CP05MTR LED sink driver

Tags: led, resistors, shift-register, constant-current, current-sink

I'm planning to use a [STP16CP05MTR](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00126634.pdf) LED sink driver to drive some LEDs in a matrix. The `STP16CP05MTR` supports constant current by the use of an external resistor marked `R-EXT` in the datasheet.

**The idea is to provide a `~20 mA` current to each LED by using *one* `1 K` resistor on `R-EXT`.**

What i **cannot** figure out from the datasheet is if this resistor should be connected to `GND` or `VDD`. Page 17 in the datasheet might suggest `GND`, but with my limited knowledge I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R-EXT resistor in figures 17-18 of the datasheet is shown connected to the R-EXT pin at one end, and a not-very-commonly-used symbol for Ground, at the other end. Thus, the resistor does need to be connected to ground.

Notice also that the GND pin connects to the same symbol, such as in Figure 17.